# Do I need to declare all my JQuery prototypes in a JQueryStatic definition file with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following code:

```
///<reference path="../typescript/jquery.d.ts" />

function addThemePrototypes() {
    var templateSetup = new Array();
    $.fn.addTemplateSetup = function(func, prioritary)
    {
        if (prioritary)
        {
            templateSetup.unshift(func);
        }
        else
        {
            templateSetup.push(func);
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to add the following:

```
  $('a').addTemplateSetup(
```

Into this same file I notice there is no intellisense and typescript does not seem to know about the addTemplateSetup prototype that I just added.

Is this the correct way for it to work or do I always need to add things like the definition for addTemplateSetup to an JQueryStatic definition file and then include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to declare it in some way to make Typescript not complain, the easiest is to declare it as any:

```
interface JQuery {
    addTemplateSetup: any;
}
```

But to get best intellisense support add info about the parameter types aswell:

```
interface JQuery {
    addTemplateSetup: (func: Function, priority: bool) =>void;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it not possible for typescript to infer the information from the file or would it only infer the information if I had added parameter types to the prototype when I was defining it? One more question. I have been declaring like this interface JQuery { addTemplateSetup(); }.  Is there a difference between this and your first declaration where you use :any ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to add :any explicitly, it's implied if no type is declared. By adding () you define it as a function (with any params) so that gives you a little more than just define it as :any. Typescript does not know of jQuery js internals. I guess if you rewrote parts of Jquery as Typescript could find out the information from $.fn-information automatically.